# Unexpected exception caught of input in PHP tag which has HTML

Tags: php, html

I Have a delete button where I want to pass a parameter to PHP function. But it gives me Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input error in chrome console. According to my knowledge, there isn't any syntax error. below you can find my code.

```
<tbody>
              <?php foreach($orderData as $order){
                $id = $order["order_id"];
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$order["order_id"]."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$order["customer_name"]."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$order["addedperson_id"]."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$order["total"]."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$order["added_date"]."</td>";
                echo "<td align='center'><button  class='btn btn-danger' name='close' id='close' onclick='".base_url()."index.php/order/suspend/".$id."'>delete</button></td>";
                echo "</tr>";

                } ?>

            </tbody>
```

This is the place where I get the error in the google console

[image: This is the place where I get the error in the google console]

Comment: `onclick` should contain JavaScript code and not just an URI. If you want a plain redirect/link, use `<a>`.

Comment: You need to put javascript to use that url in the onclick. Only href of a tags will automatically navigate to a url

Comment: @Sirko yes now it's working perfectly fine. Thank you for your clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass your Javascript code inside the Page where you will output the button, my personal suggestion is to use Jquery to manage the click event so from your php script you can echo the html code without any error or problem. Just assign an id to the button then write the `JS` code referred to the button id.

Example:

```
<tbody>
<?php

foreach($orderData as $order){
                $id = $order["order_id"];
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$order["order_id"]."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$order["customer_name"]."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$order["addedperson_id"]."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$order["total"]."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$order["added_date"]."</td>";
                echo "<td align='center'><button  class='btn btn-danger' name='close' id='close'>delete</button></td>";
                echo "</tr>";

                } 
?>
</tbody>

$('#close').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  // your code
});
```